# How to display checkbox in primevue treeselect

Tags: primevue

When I bind my two-level TreeNodes object to my TreeSelect component, I have checkboxes on the "children" options but not the parent groups.

[image]

My TreeNode object is properly structured, so far as I can tell.

```
{
    "label": "Customer Service",
    "key": "Customer Service",
    "value": "Customer Service",
    "children": [
      {
        "label": "Answering Services",
        "key": "Customer Service > Answering Services",
        "value": "Answering Services"
      }, ...

    {
    "label": "Finance and Accounting",
    "key": "Finance and Accounting",
    "value": "Finance and Accounting",
    "children": [
      {
        "label": "AP/AR",
        "key": "Finance and Accounting > AP/AR",
        "value": "AP/AR"
      },
```

I followed the directions at https://primevue.org/treeselect/ and compared their TreeNode object to my own, but see no structural differences.

My component tag looks like this...

```
<TreeSelect id="services" v-model="myservices" :options="options"
     selectionMode="checkbox" 
     display="comma" emptyMessage="No options loaded"
     placeholder="Select..."  
     class="w-full formInput" :showToggleAll="true" @update:modelValue="debugFx"
     />
```

I expect checkboxes on the parent groups.